# Группировка cs-файлов в решении

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

В решении asp.net core 2.0 три проекта. Перекинул из проекта WebApp содержимое папки migration в такую же папку проекта DataAccess - при этом группировка 00000000000000_CreateIdentitySchema и 00000000000000_CreateIdentitySchema.Designer не сохранилась:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это можно как-то поправить? Раньше можно было в [csproj-файлах поправить](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3617539/5752652):

```
<Compile Include="Migrations\201705292155224_UserTag.cs" />
<Compile Include="Migrations\201705292155224_UserTag.Designer.cs">
  <DependentUpon>201705292155224_UserTag.cs</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
```

А теперь вроде все файлы решения пересмотрел - не вижу, куда спрятали эту настройку.

И по каким словам зацепиться в поиске на большом so - не понимаю.

Answer (score 2):

Судя по [этому вопросу Джона Скита](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43846079/5752652) в проектах типа Library такое сделать в .Net Core нельзя (но это по-прежнему работает в проектах типа Application в том же самом .Net Core)

Печально.

И да, принятый в ответе хак у меня тоже не сработал, как не помогает и создание новых миграций - все они разгруппированные.