# Назначение ItemGroup с Compile=Remove в файле проекта

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, entity-framework-core, csproj

В проекте asp.net core + entity framework core мне не очень нравится, как быстро [пухнет папка миграций](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/796302/213987) и я стал часто squash'ить (как в гите — не знаю точного термина) миграции: было несколько миграций, когда добавил ещё одну и проверил, что она работает — и после этого схлопываешь.

Делается в пару шагов:

1. Нужно [удалить](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/#remove-a-migration) последнюю миграцию при помощи команды `Remove-Migration`
2. Создать заново миграцию при помощи стандартного `Add-Migration`

Это не очень удобно делать на проектах, ушедших в продакшен (на машине разработчика не проблема катать туда-сюда миграции, а обновлять прод не особо удобно) — но пока проект ещё в активной разработке с нуля, то просто милое дело.

И вот в одном проекте я держу две миграции: одна называется IdentitySchema (почти дефолтная схема asp.net identity) и ещё одна называется MyProjectName:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Только вот почему-то в файле .csproj я до сих пор вижу все удалённые транзакции:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
    ...
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="Migrations\20180330073133_фываTable.cs" />
    ...
    <Compile Remove="Migrations\20180330215324_фываTable.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Migrations\20180408111937_CreateMyAppSchema.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Migrations\20180512001200_CreateMyAppSchema.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>

  ...

</Project>
```

И я хочу понять, что это за строчки, зачем они нужны студии и можно ли их безболезненно удалить. (Вроде как можно, пробовал, но не выйдет ли это потом где-то боком?)

Comment: Точно не уверен, но оно (vs) хранит таким образом историю, пережиток прошлого, наверное ещё не почистили в коде. Сейчас, в 2017, вся история храниться в папке `.vs` в db файлах. И вероятно, есть возможность откатить назад, командами, вот оно это и содержит.

Comment: А эти файлы удалены фактически? Я если меняю у файла `Include` на `Remove`, то после загрузки проекта этот в нем отсутствует (и все места использования этого класса подчеркиваются красным), хотя физически он находится в той же папке. Таким образом, если этих файлов физически уже нет, то эти строчки ни на что не влияют

Comment: На MSDN почему-то очень сжато все это расписано, так сжато, что ничего непонятно: [ссылка](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-items?view=vs-2017#BKMK_RemoveAttribute)

Comment: @АндрейNOP Да, файлов уже физически нет. Я просто насколько помню в core перестали в csproj перечислять список всех файлов проекта (проще слияния веток делать), поэтому недоумеваю, зачем нужно хранить имена файлов, да ещё и удалённые.