# Документация на описание формата файла .csproj

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, csproj

В последних версиях Visual Studio 2017 контекстное меню проекта содержит пункт `Edit <Projectname>.csproj` — и это очень удобное дополнение к диалоговому меню свойств проекта (Alt+Enter в контекстном меню проекта).

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
    <UserSecretsId>aspnet-WebApplication1-6677AABB-BBBB-4444-99AA-123456789</UserSecretsId>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design" Version="2.1.2" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.1.6" PrivateAssets="All" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Update="Pages\_ViewStart.cshtml">
      <Pack>$(IncludeRazorContentInPack)</Pack>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Areas\Identity\Services\" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Однако сколько бы я не искал документацию с описанием структуры проекта -- всё никак не мог найти.

При этом в разных кусках офсайта майкрософт встречаются какие-то фрагменты "исправьте в csproj вот так — и заработает": без подробных объяснений что и как, но часто можно из этих обрывков восстановить логику. Ну и где-то сам [доходишь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/918806/213987) до понимания, просто сравнивая в git редакции проекта. (Вырезал два абзаца матюков и кейсов, когда подобные знания пришли в процессе отладки)

Но я уже так не могу, хочу структурированных знаний, а не собирать знания по кусочкам с потом и кровью.

Если кто-нибудь встречал описание, пусть даже непереведённое на русский — ткните в меня ссылками, буду благодарен.

Comment: [MSBuild project file schema reference](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-project-file-schema-reference?view=vs-2017)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Спасибо за ссылку! Полистал по самым непонятным компонентам типа Item Exclude или Compile Include - и по первому описание совсем куцее, а по второму отсутствует. Будет очень печально, если это всё, что есть у вендора и больше нигде нет.

Comment: Есть еще такая книга: Using MSBuild and Team Foundation Build. Вроде, по теме.

Comment: По поводу Compile Include: [MSBuild items](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-items?view=vs-2017). Но, да, документация структурирована плохо, на мой взгляд.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov не хотите собрать всё в ответ?

Comment: Ответ будет состоять, по сути, из ссылок. Не знаю, есть ли в этом смысл...