# Ошибка миграции: column already exists

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, миграция

Пытаюсь добавить миграцию:

```
dotnet ef migrations add add_ProductGroup --context migrationsdbcontext
dotnet ef database update --context migrationsdbcontext
```

И после Update выдает ошибку: "*column "ProductGroupId" of relation "Products" already exists*".

Модель ProductGroup (для нее делаю миграцию):

```
public class ProductGroup : IHaveIntegerId
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Localize] public string Title { get; set; }
        public UserGroup? UserGroup { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public int? RegionId { get; set; }
        public Region Region { get; set; }
    }
```

В таблице Products есть колонка ProductGroupId.

Я до этого создал миграцию и удалил в VS через TeamExplorer. Может, из таблицы `Products` не удалилась колонка `ProductGroupId`. Непонятно, как ее теперь удалить

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я бы в такой теме давал советы только после того, как вы сделаете бекап и чётко опишете, что делали и что где находится. Вы так небрежно описываете ситуацию, пропускаете ключевые моменты, что советовать вам что-то -- вы же радостно броситесь делать и ещё больше усугубите, понимаете наши опасения? Вы пишете "создал миграцию и удалил", а применяли ли вы её -- не пишете. И вы говорите "может из талицы не удалилась колонка" -- ну так сходите и проверьте сначала, есть ли она, а ещё стоит видимо вам посоветовать  не забыть нажать F5. Без точного описания вопроса, ситуации только вредить ответом.

Comment: можете попробовать поменять имя БД и накатить чистую базу

Comment: Я создал миграцию, применил, а потом удалил файлы `20200217112046_add_ProductGroup.cs`, `20200218132053_update_AppUser.cs`, а файл `MigrationsDbContextModelSnapshot.cs` откатил. Колонка `ProductGroupId` в таблице `Products` осталась.

Comment: Удалил колонку `ProductGroupId` из таблицы `Products`, теперь создал миграцию и при обновлении БД ругается: `relation "ProductGroup" already exists`

Comment: Окей, теперь ситуация понятна. Сделайте резервную копию, если вам данные важны, а потом можете экспериментировать со способами из моего ответа. Дело в том, что вы удалили поле, но не посмотрели содержимое таблицы dbo.__EFMigrationsHistory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

К сожалению вы некорректно сделали, удалив файлы после того, как применили транзакцию.

Правильно было сначала [откатить миграцию](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli) через `Remove-Migration` -- она выполняет все проверки структуры, аккуратно убирает добавленные поля, сама удаляет файлы миграции.

Запомните эту команду на будущее, пригодится.

Как теперь всё-таки выкрутиться из ситуации и вернуться к корректному, согласованному состоянию:

1. Вручную удалите поле через SSMS
2. В таблице базы данных __EFMigrationsHistory удалите строку с вашей удалённой миграцией 20200217112046

Это самый крайний случай (он основан на понимании как устроен и работает EF Core), так же у вас есть альтернативы.

Во-первых, если вы успели файлы положить в версионный контроль, то можете просто достать их обратно и удалить корректно через Remove-Migration

Во-вторых, если это не продакшн база, а учебно-тренировочная и вам не жалко данных, которые в ней содержатся -- можно просто удалить базу и создать заново дав команду Update-Database.

> Важно! В любом случае я бы рекомендовал вам предварительно сделать
>   бекап, на случай подстраховаться от того, что что-то пойдёт не по
>   плану.

PS И отдельно, обратите внимание, что у вас в файле *.csproj после выполнения Remove-Migration [остались строки удаления миграции](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/918806/213987), они не мешают, но я люблю чистоту, поэтому удаляю их и не коммичу.