# Как работать вместе?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я делаю игру на unity. Друг решил помочь. Какие есть сайты или программы(бесплатные) чтобы мы могли работать вместе. Спасибо

Comment: Любая система контроля версий

Comment: Visual Studio уже имеет все необходимое.

Comment: [Visual Studio | Групповая разработка ПО](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1012399/179763)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если хотите писать код одновременно на одном компьютере (не советую), можете использовать team viewer.

Если хотите отслеживать изменения друг за другом, распределять задачи, иметь возможность отката, закрытого доступа к коду, обновлению в любой момент и т.д. (очень советую), почитайте про основы использования [github](http://github.com), зарегистрируйтесь, создайте репозиторий и набивайте руку

Краткий вводный курс:

1. Скачайте [GitBash](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.26.2.windows.1/Git-2.26.2-64-bit.exe) (прямая ссылка на скачивание)
2. Зарегистрируйтесь на [github](http://github.com), создайте репозиторий, добавьте вашего друга, как контрибьютора к репозиторию.
3. Изучите основные команды (*git init, git clone, git branch, git checkout, git add, git commit, git push, git pull, git merge*) и принцип работы git в целом.
4. Изучите основные команды для работы в ОС Linux (необходимо для работы с Git Bash) (*pwd, ls, cd, touch, cat, nano, sudo*)

Также советую заранее продумать архитектуру вашего проекта и распределить задачи, выполняя их в отдельных ветках, чтобы потом не возиться с конфликтами в случае одновременного изменения одной и той же ветки.

Успехов!