# Структура ERP на .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

Помогите разобраться в теоретических вопросах.

Я внутри своей компании разрабатываю ERP-систему, которая позволяет аккумулировать данные с производственных цехов и анализировать их. В качестве архитектуры системы я рассмотрел много вариантов и увидел, что многие системы реализуют так:

MVC - CORE WEB API - MYSQL

Правильно ли я понял функционал: MVC получается нужно для генерации интерфейса и получения данных от пользователя, а  WEB API для получения данных из СУБД и обработки этих данных?

Можно ли на стороне клиента использовать целый спектр приложений UWP, Xamarin, MVC?

Comment: Ответы: "да" и "да".

Answer (score 1):

Вы начали с конца. Выбор технологии для фронтенда это по сути последнее дело.

Я постараюсь упрощенно описать стадии проектирования, надеюсь будет вам полезно. Пишу просто из головы, потому не стесняйтесь добавлять/обновлять информацию по желанию.

### Начальный документ проекта

Первым делом надо создать документ, который включает

1. Название проекта (чтобы иметь возможность одним-двумя словами делать отсылки к проекту)
2. Назначение проекта (зачем проект вобще нужен?)
3. Сроки
4. Вовлеченные стороны (менеджеры, разработчики)
5. Примерный план проекта с указанием дат и ответственных лиц. Ничего страшного, если план неточный, его всегда можно обновить/поправить

**Как пример**:

Проект **Supernova**

Назначение: В настоящее время учет и планирование ресурсов предприятия ведется ручным способом, что является

- трудозатрантым. Отдел планированияв даннй момент состоит из 17 человек
- занимает длительное время. Планирование на следуюзий месяц занимает три дня расчетов
- результат получается низкого качества. Мы имеем 20% ошибок планирования, что приводит к избытку 3% материалов не складе и недостатку 5%

Цели проекта:

- понизить количество трудозатрат (как людских, так и операционных) на 50%
- снизить время расчетов до 10 минут
- Понизить процент ошибок планирования до 5%, иметь не более 1% избытка и 1% недостатка материалов на складах

Сроки проекта: 2 квартал 2021 года

Участники:

- Главный менеджер: Вася Пупкин
- Бизнес аналитик: Лаврентий Петров
- Разработчики:

  - Александр Александров - Главный разработчик
  - Иван Иванов - Баззы данных
  - Петр Петров - Веб
  - Вася Васин - Мобильники

План проекта

- Основная техническая документация до 6.07.2020
- Разработка до 31.12.2021
- Тестирование до 25.02.2021
- Ввод в эксплуатациию до 25.04.2021

### Функциоальные требования

Функциональные требования опсывают то, что ваша система будет способна делать. 
Например, что система должна расчитывать план на следуюций месяц, или должна хранить информацию об оборудованни, или должна иметь систему аутентификации/авторизации юзера.

Также сюда часто включают так называемые User Stories, описания конкретных действий, что юзер может выполнить, зачем н их выполняет и какой результат он получает.

Также тут определяется, какие устройства будут поддерживаться, наример, нужно ли мобильное приложение? Для каких платформ? и тд.

### Макеты UI

Тут все просто, по User Stories строятся макеты интерфейса пользователя, для каждого вида взаимодействия. Отдельные макеты для мобильного приложения, веб сайта и тд.

### Точки интеграции

Тут вы описываете как ваша система будет работать с другими системами предприятия. Пункты на вскидку:

1. Интеграция с 1С
2. Интеграция с корпоративной системой аутентийикации/авторизации (например AD)
3. Выгрузка данных в биллинговую систему
4. Интеграция со скнирующими устройствами

и тд.

### Нефункциоальные требования

Здесь мы собираетм требования, напрямую не связанные с пользователями. Например:

1. Сколько данных мы планируем хранить? Какие это данные? Надо ли нам файловое хранилище? Надо ли нам поддерживать версионность? Какая ожидается нагрузка на хранилище данных? Какие требования к скорости работы и операционным тратам?
2. Какие браузеры мы поддерживаем? Какие устройства? Какой уровень поддержки ожидаем?
3. Как мы будем мониторить систему? Какие метрики снимать? Какой процесс поддержки пользователей? Автоматические оповещения?
4. и т.д.

### Архитектура проекта высокого уровня

Здесь должна быть биаграмма с описанием блоков, что в ней участвуют. Блоки сами по себе разделены по функциональном принципу. Например

[image: Архитектура проекта высокого уровня]

Дальше идет описание каждого из блоков, что он делает в кратце. Например

1. Пользовательский UI позволяет пользователю взаимодействовать с системой. Он состоит из

   - API для поддержки базовых операций с системой
   - одностраничного WEB приложения
   - Мобильного приложения для IOS и Android

### Детальная архитектура, технический документ

Вот на этом этапе вы уже знаете все блоки, что вам нужны, все требования, что предъявляются системе, всё необходимое, чтобы выбирать нужные вам технологии.

Например, если вам нужна поддержка нескольких клиентов на UI, в этом случае asp.net mvc ничем вам не поможет, ваш выбор может выглядеть как связка asp.net WeB API на бекенде и одностраничное веб приложение (Javascript, например Angular/React/Vue/etc) + мобильные приложения (IOS/Android) + настольное приложение (WPF/WinForms/UWP).

[image: ...]

Если же вы планируете, что доступ к системе будет только через веб интерфейс, нет необходимости усложнять себе жизнь, вы можете использовать asp.net mvc для вебсайта и больше ничего.

[image: ...]

Далее, что касается БД, вы также должны определиться, какие требования к БД предъявляются? Какие данные вы будете хранить? MySQL/MariaDB - неплохой выбор в общем случае, но есть и другие варианты - тот же PostgreSQL. Не выбирайте БД по принципу "что попалось на глаза", вы в любой момент времени должны четко знать, почему именно конкретная БД была выбрана. Выпишете на листочек все требования к БД, какой объем данных она должна хранить, с какой скоростью работать, как масштабироваться, сколько она стоить должна, какой у БД уровень поддержки и прочее и сопоставляйте эти требования с вашими кандидатами. Может, вам вообще нужно NoSQL решение типа MongoDB? А будет ли у вас необходимость в кеше, типа Redis? Всё это должно приниматься во внимение.

### Начало разработки

Далее идет планирование разработки, подробнее уже можно почитать тут [Visual Studio | Групповая разработка ПО](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1012399/179763)